# Impossible to reference an image from the Assets Folder

Tags: windows, image, xaml, uwp

I am currently building a Windows Universal App and the learning curve is OK. I get a response from my webservice, parse the JSON, display info in the app, but my current issue is the following one:

I tried to display an image that I put in the Assets folder, but this doesn't seem to work.

This is my layout:

[image]

As you can see, the text "Test" is correctly displayed but not the images.
On the right side, in the explorer pannel, I cannot see the files that should be here:

[image]

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

In my example, they are in the Assets/picto folder, but I have also tried the root directory Assets, as wal as creating Image folder at the same level.

I have definitely no idea how to add a simple picture, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Right-click the `picto` folder -> `Add >` -> `Add existing item`. Your items are not even in your solution. so they won't show up on the layout screen.

Comment: OK, I thought that adding them with explorer would be enough. You can post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding items in Windows explorer to the right location doesn't add them to your solution / deployment.

You have to right-click the `picto` folder -> `Add >` -> `Add existing item`. Your items are not even in your solution, so they won't show up on the layout screen.

Make sure you set the correct build target for each image.
If an image shouldn't show up, even through it's in your solution, this is often the reason.

Comment: Thank a lot, this sounds obvious after explanation, but not really intuitive when used to other IDE...